# [Error: ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements]

Tags: oracle, nestjs, typeorm, node-oracledb

I have a package in oracle named mj_order which has a function c_order. This function takes five arguments `name, location, product_Cdes, qty`. The first two arguments `name and location` are string. The last two arguments `product_codes and qty` are an array of strings and an array of numbers respectively.

```
 const product_codes = ['wrwewe', 'drgrd'];
 const qty = [3, 5];
 c_order(mj: string, kolkata: string, product_codes: string[], qty: number[]) {
   // backend logics...
 }
```

I am calling this function from my nestjs project.

```
const name = 'mj';
const location = 'kolkata';
const product_codes = ['wrwewe', 'drgrd'];
const qty = [3, 5];
return getManager().query(
    `SELECT mj_order.c_order(
        :NAME,:LOCATION,:PRODUCT_CODES,:QTY
    ) ORDER FROM DUAL`,
    [name, location, product_codes, qty]
);
```

I am getting error **driverError: [Error: ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements]**

In my terminal my query is like following

```
'SELECT mj_order.c_order(\n' +
'                :NAME,:LOCATION,:PRODUCT_CODES,:QTY) order FROM DUAL',
 parameters: [
    'mj',
    'kolkata',
    ['wrwewe', 'drgrd'],
    [3, 5],
 ],
```

Please help I could not figure out how to solve this binding of the array.
I have gone through [oracle-node-db documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlwherein) but still could not get it.

When I run DESCRIBE on my function I get the following

```
FUNCTION UPLOAD_OD RETURNS REF CURSOR
Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out 
Default?
------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ ----
 P_COM                          VARCHAR2(2)             IN             
 P_USER                         VARCHAR2(10)            IN             
 P_CUST                                                 IN             
 P_PRODUCT                                              IN             
 P_UNIT                                                 IN             
 P_QTY                                                  IN             
 P_RATE                                                 IN             
 P_DELIVERY_DATE                                        IN             
 P_PO_NUMBER                                            IN             
 P_SEND_DEPT                                            IN             
 P_ERGENT_STATUS                                        IN
```

Comment: Run DESCRIBE on mj_order.c_order and WS_OD.UPLOAD_OD and any collection or type arguments.  Update your question with this information so we know _exactly_ what you are trying to bind to.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Sir, I have updated the question

Comment: Any update, any further discoveries ? @MritunjayUpadhyay